# how to if roles in routes/web to determine which controller should handle?

Tags: laravel

I have a bunch of roles. my task is to determine which controller should handle based on their role. Say, I've loged in then redirect to /dashoard.

now, to handle this uri, I want it to be different controller. say, there is AdminController and SuperAdminController in `web.php`.

so far, i've tried like this :

```
if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1){
            Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
        }else{
            Route::get('/dashboard', [SuperAdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
            Route::get('/menu-management', [SuperAdminController::class, 'menuManagement'])->name('menu_management');
            Route::post('/change-role', [SuperAdminController::class, 'changeRole'])->name('change_role');
        }
```

of course this doesn't work, because auth data is null. But my question is, how to achieve this? is there any approach ti this?

Btw, I use jetsream for starter user management.
thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I have been read article here and there, and this is what I get so far.

in `web.php` :

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['usercheckrole:1']], function(){
        Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'=>['usercheckrole:2']], function(){
        Route::get('/dashboard', [PharmaController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'=>['usercheckrole:3']], function(){
        Route::get('/dashboard', [ProfessionalController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    });
```

`usercheckrole` middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role): Response
    {
        if (!empty($role)) {
            if(Auth::user()->role_id == $role) {
                View::composer('*', function ($view) {
                    $role_id = Auth::user()->role_id;
                    $data_menu = DB::table('role_menus')->whereRaw('find_in_set("'.$role_id.'", role_id)')->where('is_active', true)->get();
                    $view->with('__DATA_MENU', $data_menu);
                });
                return $next($request);
            }else{
                abort(403);
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that, when login as Admin, it should handle with AdminController right? but is no. rather is handled by ProfessionalController, which the last controller of the same URI. so it'slike 'overwrite' the controller. how to prevent this?

Comment: don't dirty your routes. use a middleware based on the user role to authorize what you want

Comment: ahh, alright so this is bad approach. can you show me how to do this with middleware? cause I've tried using middleware too, but it's like the controller is "overwriting" another controller.

Comment: please check my edit sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce the middleware in Controller [constructor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#controller-middleware) like this:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('usercheckrole:1');
    }
}
```

Don't forget to [register](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#registering-middleware) in `Kernel.php` your middleware in the section of `$routeMiddleware`.

Edit to solve:

What you have at the moment, is not possible to have same route to many controllers, it will re-write to the last. To have the same url `dashboard` for all roles, just have a main `DashboardController@index` with all logic from `AdminController`,`PharmaController`,`ProfessionalController` with the `dashboard()` logic by the `$user->role_id` and maybe you could reuse some code.

Comment: hmm... it seems like it doesn't work. it still trigger the ProfessionalController. tried dd() on AdminController, but no luck

Comment: I did change the order routes. so the AdminController is the last, and yes it handle with AdminController which is the same as role user (Admin), but then when login as Professional, it handle with AdminController which is wrong. When you say use ```,... $roles```, it means in the middleware parameter right? if that's the case, well it still 'ovwerwrtie' with the last controller order.

Comment: actually i did that idea. so i create 3 middleware (for each role). remove the params from usercheckrole middleware. then register it on construct in each controller. then guess what? it still handle with the last route order....

Comment: now I know, you have same name to url.. on `route:list` will show just one

Comment: ahhh yes. it only shows one... so it's not possible to do this right? if i want to make like this, maybe i should use prefix instead...

Comment: not possible like you have at the moment. you could have a url `dashboard` for all users, just have a main `DashboardController@index` with all logic from `AdminController/PharmaController/ProfessionalController@dashboard` with the `dashboard()` logic by the `$user->role_id` maybe you could reuse some code..

Answer (score -1):

Override get, post, patch, etc method of your router. It get's two params - url-subpart and array of controller name and its method. Do your business logic there

Or create your own router class as discribed here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-override-a-method-of-illuminateroutingroute-class